# Blakies concise English dictionary

Tags: vocabulary

Can anybody suggest the usefulness  of Blakies Concise English dictionary as a reference dictionary for an intermediate level student whose native language is not English? My effort to find an online version of Blakies dictionary has  been unsuccessful. Blakies dictionaries are brought out by Blakie and sons in UK in the last century.

Comment: [Published in 1963](https://www.schandpublishing.com/books/school-books/dictionaries/blackies-concise-english-dictionary/9788121942393/#.VcOxjK1rLIU), I'd advise against it!

Comment: can you elaborate some of its features?

Comment: I recommend Macmillan.

Comment: The Cambridge dictionary is quite good: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/

Comment: Please see this [meta topic](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english/739#739) for a list of recommended dictionaries.